# ERROR:While Updating

Tags: rhel, yum

I am using RHEL6.Whenever I am tryiung to update my machine it says that

```
[root@ASL-DRDO manmatha]# yum update
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
rhel-6-workstation-rhev-agent-rpms                                                                                                         
rhel-6-workstation-rpms                                                                                                                | 3.7 kB     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glib.i686 1:1.2.10-33.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libglib-1.2.so.0 for package: 1:gtk+-1.2.10-70.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libglib-1.2.so.0 for package: 1:imlib-1.9.15-14.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgmodule-1.2.so.0 for package: 1:gtk+-1.2.10-70.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgmodule-1.2.so.0 for package: 1:imlib-1.9.15-14.el6.i686
---> Package glib.x86_64 1:1.2.10-33.el6.rf will be an update
---> Package glib-devel.i686 1:1.2.10-33.el6 will be updated
---> Package glib-devel.x86_64 1:1.2.10-33.el6.rf will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:gtk+-1.2.10-70.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: libgmodule-1.2.so.0
       Removing: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.i686 (@epel)
           libgmodule-1.2.so.0
       Updated By: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Not found
Error: Package: 1:imlib-1.9.15-14.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: libgmodule-1.2.so.0
       Removing: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.i686 (@epel)
           libgmodule-1.2.so.0
       Updated By: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Not found
Error: Package: 1:gtk+-1.2.10-70.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: libglib-1.2.so.0
       Removing: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.i686 (@epel)
           libglib-1.2.so.0
       Updated By: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Not found
Error: Package: 1:imlib-1.9.15-14.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: libglib-1.2.so.0
       Removing: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.i686 (@epel)
           libglib-1.2.so.0
       Updated By: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Not found
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What does this message mean?

Comment: You appear to be switching from 32bit to 64bit packages. I'd certainly be looking to do a fresh install and migrate my configuration to it than try and upgrade through to that.

Comment: Can you add the output of "uname -a" and "lsb_release -a" please?

Comment: Using third-party repositories (with the exception of EPEL, which have a strict policy of only add-ons, _never_ conflict with the official system) you get such a mess. Write it up as a learning experience, and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

This type of issue is extensively covered in the CentOS wiki under the topic titled: [Available Repositories for CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).

In general you need to be very careful when mixing repositories such as EPEL, RPMForge, etc.

Looking at your error message it looks like you're mixing 32-bit packages with 64-bit packages.

#### For example

```
Error: Package: 1:gtk+-1.2.10-70.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: libgmodule-1.2.so.0
       Removing: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.i686 (@epel)
           libgmodule-1.2.so.0
       Updated By: 1:glib-1.2.10-33.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Not found
```

This particular error is telling you that you're mixing both 2 repositories (EPEL & RPMForge) and the packages available within them have conflicting dependencies. Additionally EPEL is 32-bit while RPMForge is 64-bit, which is compounding the problem.